# Hiding UITextField then Show them after a button is pressed

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I want to hide UITextFields until a button is pressed.

[Button]

(empty space)

[ButtonSelected]

UITextField
UITextField
UITextField
UITextField

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You would set the UITextField hidden property (inherited from UIView) to YES when you want it hidden ..... and to NO when you want to display it